# Can't find the bug in my code for queue with linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

I wrote the code in 3 files "Source.cpp,Queue.h,Queue.cpp".

Every time I run the program, it shows errors and I don't know the reason. All needed libraries are included.

//Source.Cpp "Main Function"

```
Queue<int>X;
 //trying to run the program .
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    X.Push(i + 1);
    cout << X.Size() << endl;
}
X.front();/
X.Pop();
X.front();
X.Pop();


return 0;
```

//Queue.h

//Node Class .header  file with all the functions in it.

```
template<class Mine>
class Node
{
public:
    Mine Value;
    Node<Mine> *Prev;
    Node();
    Node(Mine );
};

template<class Mine>
  //Queue Class 
class Queue
{
    int Elements;
    Node<Mine> *Front, *Back;

public:
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
    int Size();//returns Queue Size
    void Push(Mine );//Push a new value to the  back
    void Pop();//removes a value from the front
    void Clear();// delete  all the elements
    bool isEmpty();// checks if there are no elements in the queue
    Mine front();//returns the value in the front

 };
```

//Queue.cpp

//the implementation .the code that I wrote.

```
template<class Mine>
Node<Mine>::Node()
{
Value = 0;
Prev = 0;
}

template<class Mine>
Node<Mine>::Node(Mine Value)
{
this->Value = Value;
Prev = 0;
}

template<class Mine>
 Queue<Mine>::Queue()
 {
 Elements = 0;
 Front = Back = 0;
 }

 template<class Mine>
 Queue<Mine>::~Queue()
 {
 Clear();
 }

template<class Mine>
int Queue<Mine>::Size()
{
 return Elements;
}

template<class Mine>
void Queue<Mine>::Push(Mine Value) 
 {
 Node<Mine> *NEW = new Node<Mine>(Value);
 if (Front==0)
   {
    Front = Back = NEW;
    Back->Prev = 0;
    }
 else
   {
    Back->Prev=NEW;
    Back = NEW;
    Back->Prev = 0;
    }
  Elements++;
 }

template<class Mine>
void Queue<Mine>::Pop()
{
Node<T>*tmp;
assert(!isEmpty());
tmp = Front->Prev;
delete Front;
Front = tmp;
delete tmp;

if ( Elements==1)Front=Back;
Elements--;

}
  template<class Mine>
  void Queue<Mine>::Clear() 
   {
    for (int i = 0; i < Elements; i++)
     {
       Pop();
     }
   }
  template<class Mine>
  bool Queue<Mine>::isEmpty() 
  {
  return Elements == 0;
  }
  template<class Mine>
  Mine Queue<Mine>::front() 
  {
     assert(!isEmpty());
    return Front->Value;
  }
```

Every time i try to run the program it stops working.

Comment: why don't use queue stl of c++, why you are reinventing the wheel dude?

Comment: @Ahmed Samy  At least the function void Queue<Mine>::Pop() is wrong. For example this Front = tmp;
delete tmp;
 does not make sense.

Comment: Could you please addd error messages to your question?

Comment: @shashi I am trying to learn more  by implementing the stl's
 i know about the built-in functions but  I need to know the code behind them.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I will look into it, Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member function `Pop` is wrong. For starters it deletes at once two nodes in the queue

```
delete Front;
Front = tmp;
delete tmp;
```

and it does not set `Back` to 0 in case the result queue is empty after calling `Pop`.

The function can look the following way

```
template<class Mine>
void Queue<Mine>::Pop()
{
    assert(!isEmpty());

    Node<T> *tmp = Front->Prev;
    delete Front;

    Front = tmp;

    if ( --Elements == 0 ) Back = nullptr;
}
```

Also statements like this

```
Back->Prev = 0;
```

are redundant in the member function `Push` because this data member already is set to 0 in the constructor of the node.

From the design point of view the class `Node` should be an internal private structure of the class `Queue` because it is an implementation detail of the class `Queue`.

It would be more logically consistent to rename the data member `Prev` to `Next`.